# Не добавляются элементы arraylist в hashmap

Tags: java, android

Вообщем,необходимо хранить ресурсы в `Map<Integer, Integer> imageCountru = new HashMap<>();`
два листа

```
ArrayList<Integer> soundsRawResIds = new ArrayList<>();//ключ

ArrayList<Integer> mImageViews = new ArrayList<>();//значение
```

инициализирую массивы:

```
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.russia);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar1);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar2);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar3);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar4);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar5);
 mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar6);

soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.bela);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.rus);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.jap);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.li);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.engl);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.fin);
 soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.fr);
```

пытаюсь в маин классе вывести все в `recyclerview`:
ВЫВОДИТЬ НУжНО ТОЛЬКО КЛЮЧ:

```
void some() {
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = ima.imageCountru.entrySet().iterator();
        it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = it.next();
        int n = entry.getValue();
        mAdapter.addItem(n);
    }
}
```

запускаю приложение и ключ не выводится на экран(изображения),а в логах ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.recyclerview.recyclerview, PID: 6217
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x6
```

руагется на эти строки:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int resId = mData.get(position).getResId();
    holder.getItemImageView().setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(resId));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mCircleRecyclerView;
private Button mAddCircleButton;
ImageCountru ima;
private Random mRandom;
private CircleAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRandom = new Random();

    mCircleRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.circle_recycler_view);
    mAddCircleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_circle_button);

    mAdapter = new CircleAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 12);

    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch (position % 7) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    return 3;
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                    return 4;
            }
            return 3;
        }
    });

    mCircleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mCircleRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ima = new ImageCountru();
    ima.ininitialize();
    ima.add();

    some();

}

void some() {

    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = ima.imageCountru.entrySet().iterator();
            it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = it.next();

            int n = entry.getValue();

        mAdapter.addItem(n);
    }

}
```

}

```
public class ImageCountru {

public Map<Integer, Integer> imageCountru = new HashMap<>();

ArrayList<Integer> soundsRawResIds = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Integer> mImageViews = new ArrayList<>();

public void ininitialize() {
  mImageViews.add(R.drawable.russia);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar1);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar2);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar3);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar4);
mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar5);
 mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litvar6);

soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.bela);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.rus);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.jap);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.li);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.engl);
soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.fin);
 soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.fr);

}

public void add() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mImageViews.size(); i++)

    {
        for (int j = 0; j <soundsRawResIds.size(); j++)

        {
            imageCountru.put(mImageViews.get(i), soundsRawResIds.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Покажите весь код и весь стек-трейс. Но вообще `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x6` должно наводить на мысли.

Comment: @ s8am
меня навело на гугл..но там у всех все разное,я понимаю,что проблема с ресурсами,если не использовать коллекции,а тупо через массивы все делать,то в адаптер все прекрасно выводится , обновил код

Comment: 1. Посмотрите значение `resId` в `onBindViewHolder(...)`. 2. Как Вы инициализируете `mData` адаптера?

Comment: @ s8am
все работает корректно и код так же,но это  с массивами,а я переделываю под коллекции  и вылезает такая ошибка,след. я неправильно добавляю